# How can I get the count of different values of one colum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this

```
DURATION  FLAG
1         1
1         1
1         1
1         0
1         0
2         1
2         1
2         0
2         0
2         0
3         1
3         0
3         0
3         0
3         0
```

There are only two kinds of values of column FLAG, that are 1 and 0. And I want count the count of each value of FLAG the result looks like this

```
DURATION  FLAG_1_COUNT  FLAG_0_COUNT
1         3             2
2         2             3
3         1             4
```

How can I get the above result. I tried the following code but didn't return the right result.

```
df.groupby(['DURATION', 'FLAG']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`str.get_dummies` + `sum` -

```
df.set_index('DURATION').FLAG\
   .astype(str).str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)

          0  1
DURATION      
1         2  3
2         3  2
3         4  1
```

Or, the equivalent with `pd.get_dummies` -

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('DURATION').FLAG).sum(level=0)

          0  1
DURATION      
1         2  3
2         3  2
3         4  1
```

For the column names, you'd use `add_*fix` -

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('DURATION').FLAG)\
     .sum(level=0).add_prefix('FLAG_').add_suffix('_COUNT')

          FLAG_0_COUNT  FLAG_1_COUNT
DURATION                            
1                    2             3
2                    3             2
3                    4             1
```

If you need the index reset, use `reset_index` -

```
i = df.set_index('DURATION').FLAG    
pd.get_dummies(i)\
  .sum(level=0)\
  .add_prefix('FLAG_')\
  .add_suffix('_COUNT')\
  .reset_index()

   DURATION  FLAG_0_COUNT  FLAG_1_COUNT
0         1             2             3
1         2             3             2
2         3             4             1
```

---

**Option 2**
`groupby` + `value_counts` + `unstack`

```
df.groupby('DURATION').FLAG.value_counts().unstack(-1)

FLAG      0  1
DURATION      
1         2  3
2         3  2
3         4  1
```